# Unit Tests that work in VS 2019 but fail in VS 2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2022

I have the following test

```
[TestMethod]
public void Render_WithDateTimeNow_ReturnsFormattedString()
{
    var template = @"C:\temp\@(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString(""yyyy_MM_MMMM\\dd"")).csv";

    var result = new FilePathRenderer().Render(template);

    result.Should().Be(@"C:\temp\" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy_MM_MMMM\\dd") + ".csv");
}
```

The Render method looks like this:

```
public string Render(string filePath)
{
    lock (renderLock)
    {
        var result = RenderAsync(filePath).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
    }
}
```

When running this test in visual studio 2019, it passes perfectly.
But when opening the same solution and running the same test without modification in visual studio 2022, it fails with the following error:

> FilePathRenderer_Test.Render_WithDateTimeNow_ReturnsFormattedString threw exception:
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestHost.DebugAssertException: Method Debug.Fail failed with 'LanguageVersion 10.0 specified in the deps file could not be parsed.
> ', and was translated to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestHost.DebugAssertException to avoid terminating the process hosting the test.

What could be the issue here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of .net do you use in your test project?

Comment: (unrelated) `var result = RenderAsync(filePath).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` - No, no, no , no, no, noooo. Go Async _all the way_ or don't at all .

Comment: @godot: It's using .net 6

Comment: @Fildor yes I agree. I'm upgrading our solution to .net 6 and this part is in the legacy code. Refactoring this is another task for itself..

Comment: Did you explicitly set Language version 10 somewhere? If not, some migration tool may have set it. Which - I _believe_ - will make you either upgrade the Test Runner / Framework libs or explicitly downgrade that setting to lang ver 9 , perhaps?

Comment: @Fildor where can I set the language version?

Comment: Ah, good question. Let me check ... You can _see_ it in project properties and scroll down to "advanced". There should be a section "Language version"

Comment: Are you using xUnit, NUnit? You _may_ need to upgrade to avoid the error.